# Why is 'IEnumerable<T.GetProperty(identityProperty).GetType())> Set' not Valid?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic

Anyone here able to explain why I am not able to do the following?

```
Type u = typeof(T).GetProperty(identityProperty).GetType();
IEnumerable<u> keySet = null;
```

I know this may be easy for some but I really would appreciate an answer please.

Comment: Something about static typing, I guess.

Comment: ... redundant ')' in your code. EDIT: after your edit this problem is still in the title of the question...)

Comment: So, you are getting the type of T, and using it to get the identity property type? So you are assuming that you know that all of type T have an identity property? If that is the case, why isn't T an instance of an interface which then can have identity property defined? Since Interfaces can inherit and override their properties, you can then test for which interface you are actually talking to by strongly typing the parent method of this code.

Comment: Not the case, because right before the lines above, I have that   if (typeof(T).GetProperty(identityProperty) ==null)
                return result;

Answer (score 4):

Generics using static binding. That means that the type is defined while compiling your code. In your example the Type u will be defined while runtime.

But maybe the method Type.MakeGenericType() could help you ;)

Comment: How is new Foo<int>().GetType() == new Foo<string>().GetType() ?

Comment: "the compiler" DOESN'T create "a Foo-class for int's and one for string's"! that's the difference between c++ templates and c# generics... but.. your answer is still partially (99) correct

Comment: But I read somewhere that value-type generics are instantiated separately while reference type generics are instantiated as same?

Comment: Thank you Mikant for the correction. I checked it and it seams, that the compiler doesn't create multiple classes. Regardless of using value- or referencetypes.